# Delete parent record and keep child in comments table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a comments table that has the following fields:

- comment id
- parent comment id
- post id
- user id
- comment
- visibility

For the website that I'm building, I want users to be able to delete their accounts. Upon doing so, any comments made by the deleted user will be deleted as well.

My concern is, what if the comment belonging to the deleted user, has children comments? They would have a non existing parent and I don't feel like I should delete those comments automatically because they belong to the users who made them, BUT they do become irrelevant because they're in reply to a no longer existing comment.

My initial thought was to keep the deleted comment record, but delete the user id and comment. Then the visibility on all the children comments would be changed to hidden until the users of those comments choose to delete them.

Is this a good approach, is there a better way of dealing with this situation? I'm asking in terms of database design and about the concept as well.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you kept the deleted users' comments as well, but show in your front end that the user was deleted due to XX. But while deleting a user, you could have a checkbox option - delete user comments - which will delete all comments and its replies, because if you do not wish to show the child comments on your site again, it would be a waste storing them in your db.

Comment: Yeah, I like the idea of keeping the comment's place but displaying that the comment has actually been deleted... given that it has any children comments or else it might as well be completely removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping the children comments as long as either the user who posted them or the user whose conversation they belong to still exist. If both those users get deleted then you can delete them.

Also, instead of deleting users from the database you can add a flag that marks them as deleted. It's amazing how many times such things need to be undone. Then you can have a background job that deletes users more than X months old.

Comment: I like this approach. And thanks for the advice about keeping the user's account for an extended period, that's a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends on what policy you want to adhere and the senstivity of the comments itself.
In addition to you approach, you could consider the following:

`TRANSPARENT`:
You delete all the comments and also the child comments as they dont make sense without the parent. The users who made them won't have a clue as to what they commented on.

This keep the DB clean and avoids the orphan comments.

`PHANTOM`: 
User's leaf comments are deleted. Comments with child comments are now delinked from user's account and assigned to a phantom user.

Users who are still active that posted child comments will get to see all their comments which is nice.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with the second approach, but I'm probably not going to use a phantom user.